# Obtain documents by multiple ids

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a MongoDB (and for queries use Java Spring) database of persons which has unique ids. Let say that I have two ids and I want to obtain their persons. Something like this.

```
 Query q = new Query();
 Criteria c = new Criteria().orOperator(Criteria.where("id").is("1"),
                Criteria.where("id").is("2"));
 q.addCriteria(c);
 operations.find(q, Person.class);
```

But this does not work becase I use "id" field two times. Any idea?

Comment: You should be using the `$in` operator and pass an arraylist/set of ids - `[1,2]` to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ops.find(query(where("id").in([1, 2]));
```